# How do you change Eclipse theme when High Contrast in Windows is enabled?

Tags: eclipse, themes

I have High Contrast mode enabled in Windows 10. In Eclipse (Oxygen 2), the text is way too dark and I'm unable to change the Eclipse theme as it is locked as High Contrast whenever I have High Contrast enabled in Windows.

Is there a way to exclude Eclipse from being tied to Windows High Contrast so that I can use a different theme for Eclipse? 
[Eclipse with High Contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca5pV.png)

Comment: Instead of adding your solution as an edit to your question, please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: I installed the Color Theme plugin for Eclipse. After enabling High Contrast in Windows, I was able to select & apply a theme from Color Theme and it overrode the default High Contrast setting.